# Different answers for questions with how + adjective

Tags: expressions

If someone asks "How far is Brazil from Argentina", a possible answer is "It's about X kilometers". However, if someone asks "How high is this mountain?" you can answer "It's about X meters **high**". I think that "It's about X kilometers **far**" would sound weird, but I don't whether it's correct or not. Could you help me?

Comment: You're comparing two different kinds of questions. The first has two end points and simply asks for the difference; the second, however, marks neither endpoint, and only identifies the mountain, so it needs more specification in the answer. Note that the dimension in a mountain is vertical (_How high? That high_) and that has to be specified in the question. Note that it **could** be answered with just a measure phrase, like the first one, but _high_ is allowed. _How high is Mt. Baker? It's 3286 meters (high)._

Comment: @JohnLawler Height also has two endpoints - sea level and the summit. Height is the difference.

Comment: Yes, but neither is mentioned in the sentence. One has to infer them, and one should specify that that's necessary.

Comment: You wouldn't say "he's around 90 kilograms heavy", either.

Answer (score 1):

In sentences like

- How high is the mountain?
- How far is Brazil?

*high* and *far* function as adjectives, and the question asks about a quality of the adjective.

*High* can be used on its own, intensified, or qualified:

- The mountain is high.
- The mountain is very high.
- The mountain is three miles high.

*Far* can only be intensified. It can't be qualified, and it's odd on its own:

- ?Brazil is far.
- *Brazil is 12000 miles far.
- Brazil is very far.

The difference between *far* and *high* may be due to direction of measurement. Although we live in a three-dimensional world with mountains, we move on its surface and default to measuring in its two dimensions. *High* [and *deep*] can be qualified because when we measure vertically we need to specify that direction; *far* can't be qualified because it doesn't refer, and doesn't need to refer, to a direction.

If you need to qualify *far*, you need to use a word which can be qualified like *away* ("Brazil is 12000 miles away") but that's a different question. *Away* can't be used on its own in this sense (*Brazil is away) or intensified (*Brazil is very away).

Comment: I would analyze "far away" as a two-word grammatical unit here, and not as a two-component phrase.

Comment: I deliberately didn't mention *far away*.

Comment: You're right ... I clearly misread your last paragraph.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help. It makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

When you are discussing *distance* (from A to B), you have got to specify A and B, either implicitly or explicitly. In other words, distance involves two points that need to be specified.

On the other hand, *height* is a characteristic of a single object, so you only need to specify the object itself, again either implicitly or explicitly. So you can properly say:

> A is x metres high

With distance you can use *distant* similarly to *high*, but because you need to specify A and B, the phrasing is usually slightly different, e.g.:

> A is x km distant from B
>   A is x km distant [from here]

But it's often easier and clearer to say:

> The distance from A to B is x km.